# Send different rows from one txt file to another corresponding txt file

Tags: python, parsing, txt

I have a txt file (queries.txt) with rows that look like such:

```
(SELECT DATE(ingestion_time) as Ingestion_time, COUNT(ingestion_time) as Rows_Written, 'trsql_nzl.trRoute_external' as Table_ID, 'trsql_nzl' as Dataset_ID, FROM `irm-eap-edp-ingestion-nonprod.trsql_nzl.trRoute_external`  WHERE ingestion_time IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ingestion_time ORDER BY ingestion_time) UNION ALL
```

However, after the `(SELECT DATE(ingestion_time) as Ingestion_time, COUNT(ingestion_time) as Rows_Written,` portion of the row  I specific the dataset *(every single row starts like this)*, I have numerous dataset I want to create specific txt files for. Ex: **trsql_nzl**, I want to dynamically create a text file for that data and write any row that has that dataset name into it.

So that trsql_nzl.txt has all the rows that trsql_nzl in them, securebase.txt has all rows that securebase in them, etc...

How can I go about making a python script that goes and takes the value after the portion I specified and inside the ' and . then send that row to its corresponding txt file

Comment: Post an example of an entire line entry so we can parse out the portion that contains, for example 'trsql_nzl'.

Comment: I did, (SELECT DATE(ingestion_time) as Ingestion_time, COUNT(ingestion_time) as Rows_Written, 'trsql_nzl.trRoute_external' as Table_ID, 'trsql_nzl' as Dataset_ID, FROM `irm-eap-edp-ingestion-nonprod.trsql_nzl.trRoute_external`  WHERE ingestion_time IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ingestion_time ORDER BY ingestion_time) UNION ALL

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand after " I specific the dataset". Could you please review the question and correct the numerous grammatical errors?

Answer (score 1):

```
# log to read
in_file = 'in_file.txt'

# terms to search for
search_terms = ['trsql_nzl', 'securebase']

# open log
with open(in_file, 'r') as f:
    # read log
    in_lines = f.readlines()
    # read lines of log
    for line in in_lines:
        # search for each search term
        for term in search_terms:
            # if term is found, write to named file
            if term in line:
                with open(term + '.txt', 'w') as f:
                    out_lines = f.write(line)
```

Log format:

```
(SELECT DATE(ingestion_time) as Ingestion_time, COUNT(ingestion_time) as Rows_Written, 'trsql_nzl.trRoute_external' as Table_ID, 'trsql_nzl' as Dataset_ID, FROM `irm-eap-edp-ingestion-nonprod.trsql_nzl.trRoute_external`  WHERE ingestion_time IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ingestion_time ORDER BY ingestion_time) UNION ALL
(SELECT DATE(ingestion_time) as Ingestion_time, COUNT(ingestion_time) as Rows_Written, 'trsql_nzl.trRoute_external' as Table_ID, 'securebase' as Dataset_ID, FROM `irm-eap-edp-ingestion-nonprod.trsql_nzl.trRoute_external`  WHERE ingestion_time IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ingestion_time ORDER BY ingestion_time) UNION ALL
```